# Hide HTML elements before user submission

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, datagrid

I have a web form where the user chooses a date range and it binds the data to a grid view. When I run the web form, the title of each grid as well as its option to export as an excel file is shown.  Is there a way in HTML to hide those elements until the user selects the data range and the DataGrids appear? [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppE5i.jpg)

The "Report Text" is the title of each datagrid. Is there a way to hide the export buttons and titles until the user submits the date? The date fields is a javascript datepicker I am trying to see if the issue lies within the javascript or the HTML itself.

EDIT: I'll add my HTML Code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 382px;
        height: 96px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"

 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#<%=TextDateFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeDate: true,
                });
            });
            $(function(){
                $("#<%=TextDateTo.ClientID %>").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeDate: true,
                });
            });
</script>
     <asp:Label ID="Header" runat="server"><b>Tax Report App</b>  </asp:Label>
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
<asp:Label ID="StartDate" runat="server">Begin Date:   </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextDateFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Label ID="EndDate" runat="server"> End Date:   </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextDateTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">Report Text  </asp:Label>
<asp:GridView ID ="GridViewCS" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false">  
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#3090C7" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" ItemStyle- Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total Tax" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total Sales" HeaderText="Total Sales" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Complete Total" HeaderText="Total with Tax" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
</Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
   <asp:Button class="initial-hide" ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" OnClick = "ExportToExcel" />
 <br />
 <br />
  <br />
  <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server">Report Text   </asp:Label>
         <asp:GridView ID ="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false">  
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3090C7" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FL" HeaderText="State FL" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total FL" HeaderText="Sales Tax Amount FL" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Total Sales" HeaderText="Tax Exemption FL" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Complete Total" HeaderText="Total Sales FL" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" OnClick =    "ExportToExcelFL" />
<div>

</div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your code please ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I went ahead and did that. I tried a class of initial-hide, but I don't think that is correct. Does it have to do anything with being i, <body></body>?

Comment: So you want while date are not entered, button are hidden ?

Comment: Button And Text, the Export Buttons and The text that says "Report Text". I thought about going to a new form, but I figured it's not needed since what I'm trying to run is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [Show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) effect of jQuery to hide and show elements

Comment: by syntax, if I implement the Hide and Show that's, it would hide the fields where the user would input the information. I guess I may have caused confusion adding the jquery part.